# Html form method post not working correctly on localhost

Tags: html, sails.js

I recently installed `sails.js` to act as a web server to host all of my html and other files, and have come across a problem in my login form. When the html form method is set to post, I come across a 404 error, claiming it can't find the file. However, when I change the method to a get method, it loads the appropriate html file without problem (but displays the username and password in the url, yikes!). Even stranger, when I type the file path (that the post method outputs) in a separate tab, the page is loads without any problems.

The project I am working on is a learning project, so that I can learn the inner workings of a web page, using js, `jquery`, `angularjs`, `css`, `html` and so on. All I want to do is have the login form to redirect me to the 'logged in' page where all it says is 'Login Successful'. I do not have a list of registered users or anything of that type, I just want it to go to the next page! Here is the code ;)

```
<form name="login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="../html/KLASSY_LOGGED_IN.html">
    <div class="line">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="username" name="myUsername" id="username" pattern=".{6,}" placeholder="" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="line">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="myPassword" id="pwd" pattern=".{8,}" placeholder="" ng-required="true">
    </div>
    <div class="line submit">
        <input type="submit" id="cusLogin" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Each file that I reference using '../' works fine. In the link href attribute and the script src attribute, this type of file reference works fine. There is NO server code. All I want it to do is to take me to the 'logged in' page without any server code. This worked fine outside of `sails.js`, but why not inside of `sails.js`?

Comment: I'd image there is a problem with the code that defines your routes, but you haven't included that.

Comment: What? Could you restate that you messed up your grammar a bit there...

Comment: Sails.js requires you to define you routes with code. Your routes determine what the URLs do. The problem is most likely to do with the routes you have (not) set up. You have not shared your route code with us.

Comment: all we see is your client code.  What is the server code to process this form?

Comment: Do form actions act differently from activating an href on a link? Because all I want it to do is take me to the next page once some text is inputted in the Username and password fields which I'm about to add to the code shown above. Also, there is NO server code to process the action, just a url, which should just take me to the page.

Comment: GET forms make a GET request. POST forms make a POST request. Sounds like your server is set up to treat POST requests to static resources as Not Found (which is a bug, it should be Method Not Acceptable). There's no point in making a POST request to a static resource though.

Comment: Um I want it to hide the information that the get request shows in the url... But I shall see how to change that thing that treats post requests as not found, that does sound dumb.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu — I'll rephrase. There is no point in submitting data to a static resource (whether GET or POST).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but for now all I want is a simple page redirect. Later, I may learn how to make a legit login. I'm simply learning UI and UX, and just want the page redirect so that I can test the navigation quality of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a handler be some type of script you can't just point the action to this page.

`../html/KLASSY_LOGGED_IN.html`

What you could do is have the action be javascript which redirects you to that page.

Comment: Thanks Zach, I'll just find a way to use script to redirect the user. Since this thing isn't a live website, and won't keep a log of actual users. Was just testing for UI and UX purposes. Also would like to apologize for the amount of confusion this question caused. Thanks for understanding what I asked Zach!

Comment: @JacquesMathieu glad to have helped. Have fun with sails.